# How to read a color of a pixel from texture (cocos2d-js)?

Tags: textures, cocos2d-x, pixel, cocos2d-js

How to read a color of a pixel at [x,y] from texture (in cocos2d-js)?

Comment: Have you taken a look at: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/getpixel-setpixel-from-cctexture2d/685 ? Why do you want to read the color of pixels?

Comment: There is a technique to load game levels from image. I wonder if it is possible in cocos2d-js.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the supported TiledMaps? http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/tutorial/framework/html5/parkour-game-with-javascript-v3.0/chapter7/en

Comment: I can use tilemaps, but this question is about pixel reading. IMHO, every modern game engine should allow to do such simple operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such support in cocos2d framework, if someone can do that it would probably be a better answer.

However, cc.Texture2D does have a `getHtmlElementObj()` function. Now, this function can return either an image element or a canvas element. If it returns an image, you need to make a canvas from it like;

```
var canvas = $('<canvas/>')[0];
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
```

Once you have a canvas element, you should be able to get a pixel's color:

```
var data = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
var color = new Color([data[0], data[1], data[2]]);
```

And just for good measure, here is how to test if `getHtmlElementObj()` returns an image:

```
function isImage(i) {
    return i instanceof HTMLImageElement;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: P.S. Your answer is right only for the canvas rendering mode